# HttpClient.GetAsync, Invalid URI exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, httpclient, getasync

The below mentioned code doesn't work. I get the following exception in `GetAsync`:

> Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.

However, if I comment the `apiClient.BaseAddress` and specify the full URI in `apiClient.GetAsync` then it works fine!

Could someone please explain the reason?

**DEV Environment:**
VS2012, .NET 4.5, C#, ASP.NET WebForms

**Code**

```
private async Task WebAPICall()
{
    using (var apiClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        apiClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:9000/");
        apiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        apiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        apiClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);

        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage apiResponseMsg = await apiClient.GetAsync(new Uri("api/products/" + txtProductID.Text.Trim()));
            string strResponse = await apiResponseMsg.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Response.Write(strResponse);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }

    } //using (var apiClient = new HttpClient())
} //private async Task WebAPICall()
```

Comment: Providing [MCVE] is very important for "why this error happens". I.e. in this case it should be one line `var uri = new Uri("api/products/" + "productId");`  (also I understand that it may be painfully clear what the problem is - but "minimal" is important part).

Comment: If your question is more about using BaseAddress (like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23438416/why-is-httpclient-baseaddress-not-working) you may want to clarify that.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I provided the complete method because I have seen many people asking for it.

Answer (score 2):

Found the issue with the help of another post on StackOverflow. Thanks @Alexei for the URL.

Changed the URI string and it works fine.

```
HttpResponseMessage apiResponseMsg = await apiClient.GetAsync("api/products/" + txtProductID.Text.Trim());
```