# Why does my Web API return 404 on all resources when called from a Console app?

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, iis-express, iis-10

I have a little Web API, almost directly from the standard VS project template, i.e. `Home` and `Values` controllers, and lots of MVC cruft. It is set to run and debug under IIS 10.

I have set up tracing by adding the package `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Tracing` and the following code in `WebApiConfig`:

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
        SystemDiagnosticsTraceWriter traceWriter = config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
        traceWriter.IsVerbose = true;
        traceWriter.MinimumLevel = TraceLevel.Debug;
        config.Services.Replace(typeof(ITraceWriter), new SimpleTracer());
        ...
        ...            
    }
```

`SimpleTracer` is an `ITraceWriter` that writes to a text file.

When I call the API from outside the VS ecosystem, i.e. from PostMan in Chrome, a bad url, that results in a 404 error message, and the creation of a new trace file if there's not already one. Of I call it from PostMan with a good url, I get the expected result, and a trace of the request in the trace file.

When I call it from my Console app, even with a good url, I still get a 404 error response, and nothing is written to the trace file. I made sure by removing it and IIS doesn't even re-create it when using the `.exe` client.

If I call it from the compiled `.exe` from outside VS, I get the same error.

Then, when I set the Web API to use IIS Express, everything works perfectly. Do I need CORS for calls from non-web apps, does IIS need an extra header in this case? What is wrong?

**EDIT A:** This is the request when I use PostMan, and it returns a 200 and the expected list of strings.

```
GET /DemoApi/api/values HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: f9454ffc-6a8d-e1ed-1a28-23ed8166e534
```

and the response and headers:

```
["value1","value2","value3","value4","value5","value6","value7"]

Cache-Control →no-cache
Content-Length →64
Content-Type →application/json; charset=utf-8
Date →Tue, 13 Dec 2016 06:20:07 GMT
Expires →-1
Pragma →no-cache
Server →Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNet-Version →4.0.30319
X-Powered-By →ASP.NET
```

**EDIT B:** This is the request sent using HttpClient:

```
GET http://abbeyofthelema/api/values HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Host: abbeyofthelema
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

The only real difference is that because Fiddler doesn't capture traffic from localhost, I had to use my computer name instead. The same recipient still gets the request.

The response here is:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 13 Dec 2016 08:07:25 GMT
Content-Length: 4959
```

Comment: 404 states that the service is not found, meaning that no one is listening on the address/port. Could be something in your test environment. If you are not using self-hosting, the service should be deployed to an IIS, in order for you to call the service. Here you should double check the port that it is running on.

Comment: Can you post a full http request and response including headers?

Comment: @Michael I know what a 404 is, and I quote myself from the question, "Of [or] I call it from PostMan with a good url, **I get the expected result**...".I can **never** get the expected result when the API is not properly set up and listening on IIS.

Comment: @matcheek I've posted the full successful request and response, with headers, This is when I use PostMan. I'm trying to figure out how to lof this raw data using `HttpClient` and will post those soonest.

Comment: Try using for example `client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost/webapi/");` and then `HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/values");` instead of `client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost/webapi");` and `HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("/api/values");`

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23438416/why-is-httpclient-baseaddress-not-working

Comment: Thank you so much, @BNK. Make that an answer, so I can give you some points. Just include the link, and a summary of what the other answer says.

Comment: When I come back in a year or so.  Remember to add app.MapControllers();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to **Timothy Shields** at the following link

[Why is HttpClient BaseAddress not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23438416/why-is-httpclient-baseaddress-not-working)

> *You must place a slash at the end of the BaseAddress, and you must not place a slash at the beginning of your relative URI*