# An invalid request URI was provided. The request URI must either be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set. Trying to consuming a webservice

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient, webservice-client

I am trying to Consume a Web Service using HttpClient in .NET and after I did all steps mentioned in [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client).

I get the following exception:

> **An invalid request URI was provided. The request URI must either be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set.**

Here is my class:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string id_default_group { get; set; }
    public string id_lang { get; set; }
    public string newsletter_date_add { get; set; }
    public string ip_registration_newsletter { get; set; }
    public string last_passwd_gen { get; set; }
    public string secure_key { get; set; }
    public string deleted { get; set; }
    public string passwd { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string id_gender { get; set; }
    public string birthday { get; set; }
    public string newsletter { get; set; }
    public string optin { get; set; }
    public string website { get; set; }
    public string company { get; set; }
    public string siret { get; set; }
    public string ape { get; set; }
    public string outstanding_allow_amount { get; set; }
    public string show_public_prices { get; set; }
    public string id_risk { get; set; }
    public string max_payment_days { get; set; }
    public string active { get; set; }
    public string note { get; set; }
    public string is_guest { get; set; }
    public string id_shop { get; set; }
    public string id_shop_group { get; set; }
    public string date_add { get; set; }
    public string date_upd { get; set; }
    public string reset_password_token { get; set; }
    public string reset_password_validity { get; set; }

}

class Program
{

    static void ShowProduct(Customer customer)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Email: {customer.email}\tFirst Name: {customer.firstname}");
    }

    static async Task<Uri> CreateCustomerAsync(Customer customer)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/customers/1?output_format=JSON", customer);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        // return URI of the created resource.
        return response.Headers.Location;
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        RunAsync().Wait();
    }
    static async Task RunAsync()
    {
        NetworkCredential hd = new NetworkCredential("INHFTLZLMLP1TUTJE7JL9LETCCEW63FN", "");
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler {Credentials = hd };
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/newprestashop/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            try
            {

                Customer customer = new Customer();
                var url = await CreateCustomerAsync(customer);
                // Get the product
                customer = await GetProductAsync(url.PathAndQuery);
                ShowProduct(customer);


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    static async Task<Customer> GetProductAsync(string path)
    {
        Customer customer = null;
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            customer = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Customer>();
        }
        return customer;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your web service is up and running at http://localhost:8080? I would launch the web api project and add a break point at the start of the method (index) of the controller (newprestashop) you are trying to hit. Then, make your call from your client.

Comment: i test in post man it work great

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BaseAddress is there so that you can make all the calls relative to the the BaseAddress.  It works, you just need to know some of the idiosyncrasies of BaseAddress [Why is HttpClient BaseAddress not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23438416/why-is-httpclient-baseaddress-not-working)

But your problem is that you are instantiating a new HttpClient in each method.

```
static async Task<Uri> CreateCustomerAsync(Customer customer)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    //you never set the BaseAddress 
    //or the authentication information
    //before making a call to a relative url!
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/customers/1?output_format=JSON", customer);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    // return URI of the created resource.
    return response.Headers.Location;
}
```

A better way would be to wrap the HttpClient call in a class and it up in the constructor, then share it in any of your methods

```
    public WrapperClass(Uri url, string username, string password, string proxyUrl = "")
    {
        if (url == null)
            // ReSharper disable once UseNameofExpression
            throw new ArgumentNullException("url");
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username))
            // ReSharper disable once UseNameofExpression
            throw new ArgumentNullException("username");
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password))
            // ReSharper disable once UseNameofExpression
            throw new ArgumentNullException("password");
        //or set your credentials in the HttpClientHandler
        var authenticationHeaderValue = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
            // ReSharper disable once UseStringInterpolation
            Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", username, password))));

        _httpClient = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(proxyUrl)
            ? new HttpClient
            {
                DefaultRequestHeaders = { Authorization = authenticationHeaderValue },
                BaseAddress = url
            }
            : new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler
            {
                UseProxy = true,
                Proxy = new WebProxy
                {
                    Address = new Uri(proxyUrl),
                    BypassProxyOnLocal = false,
                    UseDefaultCredentials = true
                }
            })
            {
                DefaultRequestHeaders = { Authorization = authenticationHeaderValue },
                BaseAddress = url
            };

        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Clear();
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    }

    public async Task<Member> SomeCallToHttpClient(string organizationId)
    {
        var task = await _httpClient.GetStringAsync(<your relative url>));

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeType>(task,
            new JsonSerializerSettings {ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()});
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I bet you need the complete url address. The url is not relative to the caller when using HttpClient.

```
static async Task<Uri> CreateCustomerAsync(Customer customer)
{
   HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
   HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("http://www.fullyqualifiedpath.com/api/customers/1?output_format=JSON", customer);
   response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

   // return URI of the created resource.
   return response.Headers.Location;
}
```

Comment: works great the exception is gone but it gives another " Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized)."

Comment: That means you need to authenticate prior to making your api call. The endpoint was reached and rejected due to lack of authorization.

Comment: Your authorization problem is the same problem as your BaseAddress one.  you instantiate HttpClient and never set the values.  See my answer.

Comment: I would actually give the answer to @Fran. I solved your immediate problem, however, his answer solves with a better overall solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you copied the URL from somewhere, check it for non-visible characters. Paste the URL string into a browser, and see if anything gets escaped oddly.

I had this same problem with a seemingly normal URL. When I pasted it into a browser and tried to retrieve it, the beginning of it turned into this:

```
%E2%80%8Bhttps
```

There was some non-visible Unicode character at the start of the string that the browser reveled by encoding it.

Back in code, when I put my cursor at what looked like the start of the string and pressed "Backspace," the cursor did not appear to move. In reality, it was deleting that non-visible character.

It worked fine after that.