# What is the advantage of setting `BaseAddress` property of `HttpClient`

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

We call several APIs of multiple domains in our project using `HttpClient`. I am creating a common `HttpClient` to be used for all these API calls. I am confused between two approaches to implement this:

1. Create a singleton class for `HttpClient` and use that for every call by passing API URIs in `get/post/put` methods.
2. create a singleton class for `HttpClientHandler` which will be shared among all `HttpClient`s and create one `HtppClient` for each domain by setting the `BaseAddress` property. Now we can call the APIs by passing the relative paths in `get/post/put` methods.

Which one is the better approach?

Is there any benefit of presetting the `BaseAddress`? If not, why is this property provided?

Comment: Take a look here for an example of `BaseAddress`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23438416/why-is-httpclient-baseaddress-not-working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you choose option 1, the `BaseAddress` of course should not be used, as you'd keep overwriting it and you'd have to avoid two threads updating it before one of them has had a chance to send its request.

If you choose option 2, you can configure your `HttpClient` per API once (for instance, read `BaseAddress` and `Timeout` from a configuration file). Relative uri's can then be supplied without having to prepend the base address for each request.

Which is better I guess depends on whether you want to be able to configure properties such as `Timeout` or `MaxResponseContentBufferSize` for all APIs (option 1) or per API (option 2), I don't have a definitive "this one is better" answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about option 3: **One HttpClient instance per API (domain) being called.** It's a little easier to implement than option 2, still allows you to use a different set of stateful properties (`DefaultRequestHeaders`, etc.) per API, and still minimizes the number of open sockets lying around, avoiding [this infamous problem](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/). This would be my recommendation.

`BaseAddress` exists solely so you can use relative URIs instead of absolute URIs for individual requests.

Comment: I am not seeing any complexity in passing a common `HttpClientHandler` while creating `HttpClient` in option 2. Am I missing something?

Comment: @ctor Just that you don't need to deal with a handler explicitly at all. Looking at option 2 again, I think my suggestion is exactly the same, minus the handler singleton. I don't think that gains you anything, unless *I'm* missing something.