# Converting json to c# object

Tags: c#, asp.net, jsonconverter

I have an api that returns me a json with information about the data transition and an array with data

```
{
    "code": "200",
    "result": true,
    "message": "",
    "data": {
        "item": [
            {
                "id": "5",
                "descricao": "TesteDesc",
                "observacao": "TesteObs",
                "status": "1"
            },
            {
                "id": "7",
                "descricao": "TesteDesc",
                "observacao": "TesteObs",
                "status": "1"
            },
        ],
        "count": 2
    }
}
```

I have a class that is referring to the return of items

```
class Category
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Descricao { get; set; }
     public int Status { get; set; }
     public string Observacao { get; set; }
 }
```

Main.cs

```
 var stringJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

my string stringJson gets the following value

```
"\r\n\r\n{\"code\":\"200\",\"result\":true,\"message\":\"\",\"data\":{\"item\":[{\"id\":\"5\",\"descricao\":\"TesteDesc\",\"observacao\":\"TesteObs\",\"status\":\"1\"}],\"count\":2}}"
```

but when I try to convert

```
var Data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Category>>(stringJson);
```

error is displayed

> Erro: cannot deserialize the current json object (e.g.
>   {"name":"value"}) into type ...

How can I create an array of objects with json data?
taking only the date and item

is it possible for me to retrieve the values formally alone, for example I make a variable bool status = jsonConvert.get ("status"); something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow structure! Your json contains more than just a `List<Category>`. When deserialzing, you will have to deserialzr to a class like the following

```
 class Wrapper {
      public string code {get;set;}
      public bool result {get;set;}
      public string message {get;set;}
      public Data data {get; set;}
  }


 class Data {
      public List<Category> item {get;set;}
      public int count {get; set;}
 }
```

Then you can deserialize using

```
 Wrapper d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Wrapper>(stringJson);
```

And access your items with

```
d.data.item
```

Follow casing! In your json all properties start with a lower case letter, wheras in your `Category` class they are upper case. Alternatively you can define a contractresolver which ignores casing. See the docs on how that works.

Follow types! In your json `id` and `status` are strings, in your `Category` class they are integers. You may be able to work around that with contract resolver too. See the docs for details.

Answer (score 2):

Frist you outer JSON format is an object, not an array.

You models will like this.

```
public class Item
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string descricao { get; set; }
    public string observacao { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public List<Item> item { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public string code { get; set; }
    public bool result { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialize `json`

```
var Data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Category>(stringJson);
List<Item> items = Data.data.item;
//items get info from items
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can control the serialization using attributes, in order to keep your property names consistent with the [general naming conventions used in the .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions) :

```
public class Item
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("descricao")]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("observacao")]
    public string Observacao { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("item")]
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("count")]
    public int Count { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    [JsonProperty("code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("result")]
    public bool Result { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public Data Items { get; set; }
}
```

Code to deserialize the json string:

```
string json = @"{
    ""code"": ""200"",
    ""result"": true,
    ""message"": ""some message"",
    ""data"": {
        ""item"": [
            {
                ""id"": ""5"",
                ""descricao"": ""TesteDesc"",
                ""observacao"": ""TesteObs"",
                ""status"": ""1""
            },
            {
                ""id"": ""7"",
                ""descricao"": ""TesteDesc"",
                ""observacao"": ""TesteObs"",
                ""status"": ""1""
            },
        ],
        ""count"": 2
    }
}";

Response response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

Install Newtonsoft.Json from Nuget then Try it

```
string JsonData = "\r\n\r\n{\"code\":\"200\",\"result\":true,\"message\":\"\",\"data\":{\"item\":[{\"id\":\"5\",\"descricao\":\"TesteDesc\",\"observacao\":\"TesteObs\",\"status\":\"1\"}],\"count\":2}}";
JObject jobject = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JsonData);
```