# PUT requests to LogStash fail when sent using HttpClient, succeed when sent using cURL

Tags: rest, elasticsearch, logstash, elasticsearch-plugin

[Here](http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/f1f02) is my `logstash.conf` file. (Apologies for not pasting the code here directly; StackOverflow does not allow posts exceeding a certain code-to-text ratio.)

My remote VM, which also hosts my ElasticSearch and LogStash servers, listens on Port 8080.

On my local machine, I periodically send zipped folders (containing JSON documents) over TCP to my remote server, which receives the data into a memory stream, unzips the folders, and sends the contents to LogStash. LogStash in turn forwards the data to ElasticSearch.

I am currently testing the workflow with some dummy data.

On my remote server, here is the method for receiving data over TCP:

```
private static void ReceiveAndUnzipElasticSearchDocumentFolder(int numBytesExpectedToReceive)
{
    int numBytesLeftToReceive = numBytesExpectedToReceive;

    using (MemoryStream zippedFolderStream = new MemoryStream(new byte[numBytesExpectedToReceive]))
    {
        while (numBytesLeftToReceive > 0)
        {
            // Receive data in small packets
        }

        zippedFolderStream.Unzip(afterReadingEachDocument: LogStashDataSender.Send);
    }
}
```

Here is the code for unzipping the received folder:

```
public static class StreamExtensions
{
    public static void Unzip(this Stream zippedElasticSearchDocumentFolderStream, Action<ElasticSearchJsonDocument> afterReadingEachDocument)
    {
        JsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();

        foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in new ZipArchive(zippedElasticSearchDocumentFolderStream).Entries)
        {
            using (JsonTextReader jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(new StreamReader(entry.Open())))
            {
                dynamic jsonObject = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<ExpandoObject>(jsonReader);

                string jsonIndexId = jsonObject.IndexId;
                string jsonDocumentId = jsonObject.DocumentId;

                afterReadingEachDocument(new ElasticSearchJsonDocument(jsonObject, jsonIndexId, jsonDocumentId));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the method for sending data to LogStash:

```
public static async void Send(ElasticSearchJsonDocument document)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = 
        await httpClient.PutAsJsonAsync(
            IsNullOrWhiteSpace(document.DocumentId) 
                ? $"{document.IndexId}" 
                : $"{document.IndexId}/{document.DocumentId}",
            document.JsonObject);

    try
    {
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"{response.Content}");
}
```

The `httpClient` referenced in the `public static async void Send(ElasticSearchJsonDocument document)` method was created using the following code:

```
private const string LogStashHostAddress = "http://127.0.0.1";
private const int LogStashPort = 31311;

httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri($"{LogStashHostAddress}:{LogStashPort}/") };
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

When I step into a new debug instance, the program runs smoothly, but dies immediately after executing `await httpClient.PutAsJsonAsync` for each of the documents contained inside the zipped folder -- `response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();` is never hit; neither is `Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);` nor `Console.WriteLine($"{response.Content}");`.

Here is an example of `ElasticSearchJsonDocument` that is passed to the `public static async void Send(ElasticSearchJsonDocument document)` method:

[image]

When I ran the same `PUT` request using cURL, the `Book` index was successfully created, and I could then a `GET` request to retrieve the data from ElasticSearch.

## **My questions are:**

1. Why did the program die immediately (with no visible exception messages) after executing `await httpClient.PutAsJsonAsync(...)` for each of the JSON document inside the received zipped folder?
2. What changes should I make to ensure that I can make successful `PUT` requests to LogStash using a `HttpClient` instance?

Answer (score 0):

I changed my `httpClient` instantiation code from

```
httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri($"{LogStashHostAddress}:{LogStashPort}/") };
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

to

```
httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

And I changed `await http.Client.PutAsJsonAsync(...)` to

```
HttpResponseMessage response =                
    await httpClient.PutAsJsonAsync(
        IsNullOrWhiteSpace(document.DocumentId)
            ? $"{LogStashHostAddress}:{LogStashPort}/{document.IndexId}"
            : $"{LogStashHostAddress}:{LogStashPort}/{document.IndexId}/{document.DocumentId}",
        document.JsonObject);

response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

It turns out that the `BaseAddress` field in `HttpClient` is [extremely user-unfriendly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23438417/3559686), so instead of wasting more time on it, I decided to just eliminate it entirely.