# how to correctly Implement GetJsonAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-blazor

I am trying to make Blazor APP that returns Employees list but when trying to return the list using GetJsonAsync the following error appears ....

**JsonException: '<' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 1 | BytePositionInLine: 0.**

Controller Files:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class EmployeesController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IEmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
    

    public EmployeesController(IEmployeeRepository employeeRepository)
    {
        this.employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetEmployees()
    {

        try
        {
            return Ok(await employeeRepository.GetEmployees());
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError
                   ,"Error retrieving data from the database");
            
        }

    }
```

Services Class:

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Employee>> GetEmployees()
    {
        return await httpClient.GetJsonAsync<Employee[]>("employees");
    }
```

Blazor Base Class:

```
 public class EmployeeListBase : ComponentBase
{

    [Inject]
    IEmployeeService EmployeeService { get; set; }

    

    public IEnumerable<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Employees = (await EmployeeService.GetEmployees()).ToList();
    }


}
```

Comment: `return await httpClient.GetJsonAsync<Employee[]>("employees");`  "employees" is a very strange Uri. Have you set `HttpClient` `BaseAddress` ? It looks `GetJsonAsync` call receives HTML page. Like 404 status page

Comment: i did in the configure services  ` services.AddHttpClient<IEmployeeService, EmployeeService>(client =>
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44379/");
    });`

Comment: Make sure you include the http or https  in the BaseAddress Uri. Also have you verified your endpoint gets hit (by placing a breakpoint in the EmployeesController.GetEmployees method?

Comment: @RomanKalinchuk "employees" is perfectly valid. OP has set the base address and their controller route does not include 'api/'. So the correct route to request is "employees" however I think they need to fix the base address (which btw, [also has some oddities](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23438417/491907)

Comment: That error usually means there was HTML returned, not json. It is probably a 500, 404, etc., view which cannot be parsed as json.

Comment: Thank you all for help ... after reading the oddities i fixed the URI and it worked .. You must place a slash at the end of the BaseAddress, and you must not place a slash at the beginning of your relative URI