# C# How to retrieve Dynamics Finance and Operations entity records

Tags: c#, erp, dynamics-365-operations

I am struggling to retrieve an entity records in Microsoft ERP Dynamics Finance and Operations. I was able to get authentication access but when I use the http request it show me an error.

My code:

```
 string clientId = "clientId";
        string clientSecret = "clientSecret";
        string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId";
        string resourceUrl = "https://trial-ub2dbh.sandbox.operations.dynamics.com/"; // Org URL

        try
        {
            ClientCredential credentials = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
            var authContext = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext(authority);
            var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceUrl, credentials);

            HttpClient httpClient = null;
            httpClient = new HttpClient();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("OData-Version", "4.0");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://trial-ub2dbh.sandbox.operations.dynamics.com/data/$metadata#");

            var response_Contacts = httpClient.GetAsync("PartyContacts").Result;

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.ToString();
        }
```

The error is :

> bad request

How can I make this retrieve?

Comment: Did that work??

Answer (score 0):

The url should be different, for retrieving data - the endpoint should be different from **$metadata** query.

You have to use below endpoint for retrieving **Vendors**.

```
httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://trial-ub2dbh.sandbox.operations.dynamics.com/data/");
var response = httpClient.GetAsync("Vendors").Result;
```

instead of below line:

```
httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://trial-ub2dbh.sandbox.operations.dynamics.com/data/$metadata#");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer i did what you suggested but is  giving the same error

Comment: @taniguchisantos are you able to put that url in browser address bar to see results?

Comment: yes i put that url in the browser and it is working the records are showing but in line: var response_Contacts = httpClient.GetAsync("LegalEntityContacts").Result;                                             is giving the error "bad request"

Comment: @taniguchisantos see this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/23438417